# "UserNotificationsUI" is not available when building for UIKit for Mac error

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, push-notification, uikitformac

- My app has Service & Content Extension Notifications targets for
  supporting Rich Remote Notifications which work as expected on
  iPad/iPhone iOS 13 & below
- I have installed Xcode 11-beta & macOS Catalina 10.15-beta
- On building with the new `UIKitForMac` I get the following error -

```
"UserNotificationsUI" is not available when building for UIKit for
Mac. You may need to restrict the platforms for which this framework
should be linked in the target editor.
```

- First tried adding `#if canImport() ... #endif` around instances of `UserNotificationsUI` which didn't work
- Then removed the Extension Targets which is also not working.

Anyone facing a similar issue?

[image: Xcode11 screenshot]

Comment: I'm facing an issue similar to this: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3144. Static libs that do contain the desired architecture are being rejected by XCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closed source Third party framework that I was using had `UserNotificationsUI` linked.

The build error was because UIKitForMac doesn't support Mobile specific frameworks like UserNotifications which is the correct behaviour.

Removing the Third Party dependency resolved the issue for me.